# Can't figure out "ïllegal unit of measure" in IEEE Access Latex Template

Tags: ieeeaccess

I'm attempting to transfer my previously formatted paper which was in the Springer Nature format to IEEE Access, and despite there being no error whatsoever in the original, the new document marks every figure and table with "illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" and also an "undefined control sequence" errors. I've looked at the documentation and even copy pasted the code on the Overleaf website, still produces the same error.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\renewcommand{\thevol}{1}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=6in]{HD_EEG_FlowChart.png}
    \caption{Biological signal data applications flowchart}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure*}
...
\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! It seems that before your `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}` should have (at least one) figure inserted by `ieeeaccess` syntax: `\Figure[ht]{example-image-duck}
           {Test figure \label{fig:test}}`

Answer (score -1):

You need to download complete template from [IEEE-Template Selector](https://template-selector.ieee.org/). All `.png`, `.map`, `.pfb` and `.tfm` files are needed. You should put them in the same directory as the `ieeeaccess.cls` file.